# Rails Helpers in rspec features using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, helper

I have run into this issue a few times, and was wondering what the proper way to deal with it is.

Basically, I am writing a simple capybara feature in rspec:

```
describe 'Some Feature', type: :feature do
  context "when visiting the /some/page/:id" do
    it "shows Desired Content" do
      visit "/admin/pages/:id"
      expect(page).to have_content("Desired Content")
    end
  end
end
```

In the view at `views/admin/pages/show.html.erb` is a call to a helper method located in the corresponding helper (Admin::PagesHelper).  In normal rails, these helper module methods are automatically available for use.  When i run this feature test though, I get an error stating

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `some_admin_pages_method' for #<#<Class:0x007fe1ace881f0>:0x007fe1ad364d40>
```

What is the proper approach to getting these helper methods to be available when running my rspec features?

Comment: do you have a `spec_helper.rb`? Put your method there!

Comment: by the way, after your `context "when visiting the /some/page/:id" do` you should have a `it "visit page" do`

Comment: thanks, it does. just a type in the questions (fixed).   regarding your solution of putting it in `spec_helper.rb`, that seems to not be a solution that scales since I would potentially have to continue adding helper methods already defined in my helpers in this class.

Comment: ok, let's see. In the test you posted, do you want to use a method defined where?

Comment: The purpose of feature specs are not really to test a specific method, but rather to test a high level path through the application.  There will always be the possibility of some helper method being called within a view that is `visit`ed by capybara, which is totally acceptable.  It doesn't seem right to have to recreate a helper method in the test suite when the idea isn't to test any given method but rather overall functionality.

Comment: The error you're getting is from the app attempting to render the page when you visit it.  What driver are you using with Capybara?  Assuming you have required capybara/rspec and capybara/rails in your spec_helper or rails_helper and setup rspec-rails correctly then the helpers should be autoloaded by rails when the application is started -  Have you customized the app passed to the capybara driver registration?  or are your helpers in non-standard directories?